# translate an android app by translation editor

Tags: android, language-translation

I'm having trouble with translating my app. I saw that I need to go to the translation editor, however after open the translation editor I cant see the text that I need to translate and there are not any langues suggested. 
I have android studio 2.2.3

[image]

Comment: text you need to translate is shown in default value.

Answer (score 1):

Click Globe icon (above key column) and select the language you want to translate. A new column ( and strings.xml file ) will be added for the selected language. Now you can add translated text in that column or directly edit the new strings.xml

After adding new language, release builds require translation for each string. If you don't need to provide translation for some of the strings you can mark them as untranslatable in translation editor or edit strings like

```
<string name="demo" translatable="false">Demo</string>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I added a language but still I cant see the all strings (text views) that needs to be translated, only the name of the app is shown. only one line is shown: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Translate Demo</string>
</resources>

Comment: strings available in strings.xml are the ones which can be translated, if you are using hard coded strings then you need to move them to xml file.

Comment: Great! thank you, after I did that, How can I display the app in the different language I just translated?

Comment: you need to change device language

Comment: where do I change it? I tried changing the language from  emulator settings. when I run the app it keeps showing me in English language . do I need to change also the local settings?